# interrupt the possibility to click a button during a tcpclient check

Tags: c#

I have a button on my program that checks a port. but if I put a port that is closed and I click to test it, if it is open I immediately get the green button. If it is not open instead the program is "freezed" for about ten seconds and then it gives me the red button. The problem is that if by mistake I click on the button while the program is in this phase of "freeze", then when it ends, restarts from the beginning and re-freezes, probably because it still felt the button click for the second time. how can I prevent this from happening?

**button_click**

```
private void bt_check_port_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bt_check_port.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    try
    {
        tcpClient.Connect(tb_ip_test.Text, Int32.Parse(tb_port_test.Text));
        bt_check_port.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        bt_check_port.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can disable button for the duration (but this will take keyboard focus away) or use a `bool` field which will be set to `true` for duration of *unwanted* clicks (check for it and ignore clicks).

Comment: Be aware of the limited utility of this sort of check. It tells you that a port is open. It tells you *nothing* about the ability of whatever opened the port to perform its actual job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you should go async, so you don't block the gui for long running tasks.
2. Then bypass the code while its executing, so it's not executed in parallel.
3. Also you should visibly inform the user that the button is currently not working(e.g. disable the button or display a wait indicator).

something like this:

```
private bool isWorking = false;
private async void bt_check_port_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!isWorking)
  {
    isWorking = true;
    try
    {
      bt_check_port.Enabled = false;
      bt_check_port.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
      string ip = tb_ip_test.Text;
      string port = tb_port_test.Text;
      bool portAwailable = await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
          TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
          try
          {
            tcpClient.Connect(ip, Int32.Parse(port));
            return true;
          }
          catch (Exception)
          {
            return false;
          }
        });
      bt_check_port.BackColor = portAwailable ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }
    finally
    {
      isWorking = false;
      bt_check_port.Enabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```